# What are the significant memory and GC differences between Visual Studio's hat operator and C++ shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Aside from cross-platform, cross-compiler compatibility, what are the significant differences between Microsoft Visual C++ (C++ Component Extensions) Handle to Object Operator (^) and C++ 11 std::shared_ptr?

Both seem to support automatic garbage collection through the use of reference counting and I would assume require some additional memory to track this information.  Is this extra memory overhead significant and does it differ greatly between the two implementations?

Additionally, are there ways to manage when the garbage collection occurs in either the MS C++ Component Extensions or C++ 11 environments to prevent stalling at undesirable times?

MSDN Documentation:
[Handle to Object Operator (^) (C++ Component Extensions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk97tc08.aspx)

C++ 11 smart_ptr: [std::shared_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/)

Comment: That stuff is all orthogonal. No way to give concise and correct answers.

Comment: I don't understand your use of orthogonal.  The memory overhead of each implementation should be an understood component, but I wasn't able to find any documentation regarding where or how much is involved per pointer.  Also, if there are methods for controlling when GC happens in each environment, it would be useful to control the performance of the program.

Comment: You're really better off thinking of MS CLI and standard C++ as two completely different languages; intended to run in two completely different environments.  IMHO...

Comment: *Both seem to support automatic garbage collection through the use of reference counting*. Do you believe CLR managed objects use *reference counting*?

Comment: @CodeWriter Read _in no way comparable_.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi linked articles says so: _The compiler uses the COM reference counting mechanism_

Comment: @frymode, on the WIndows Runtime, not on the CLR (scroll down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` does not use reference counting, at least not solely.

`^` handles circular references.  So if `A` has a `^` to `B`, and `B` has a `^` to `A`, and nobody else has a `^` to either, they will be cleaned up (eventually).

`^` is also a non-deterministic collector of garbage.  There are little to no guarantees about when unreachable objects will be cleaned up.

`shared_ptr` is a reference counting smart pointer.  When every `shared_ptr` using that reference counting block reaches zero, the delete action is taken.

If you have `A` with a `shared_ptr<B>`, and that `B` has a `shared_ptr<A>` back to `A`, then the two will happily exist forever.

At program shutdown, if the delete action cleans up in-process memory resources, they will be cleaned up.  If the delete action does something else, it will not ever be invoked (without manually breaking the loop).

`shared_ptr` simply states that everyone who has a copy of it has equal ownership rights over the thing in question.  When the last owner gives up its rights, at that point the delete code (which can do almost anything) is run.

As such, destruction is deterministic (if somewhat tricky to determine when it happens locally).

For memory based resources, where objects own nothing of interest except memory, `^` style memory management isn't horrible.  But once you are owning resources that *are not* memory (are "more expensive", like file handles, network connections, threads, etc), you cannot casually let them hang around.

So `^` based lifetime management doesn't work anymore.

`shared_ptr` based lifetime management does a bit better, but it still less than ideal, as tracking down effective resource leaks (where a resource lifetime is longer than it should be, ideally) is still a pain with shared ownership of lifetime.

`unique_ptr`, with its single point of responsibility, makes tracking down the lifetime issue of things easier.

In short, `^` is great when you have nearly infinite resources and don't care if they leak for a while before cleaning up.  `shared_ptr` is great when you have a strict understanding of shared ownership (you understand who exactly should be sharing ownership, and who should have weak ownership, etc).  `unique_ptr` and actual value-based data is best when you actually have resources whose lifetime should be well controlled.

Answer (score 1):

Garbage Collection and Reference Counting are fundamentally different techniques. However, comparing C++/cli and C++, the most important difference is determent deallocation/destruction. With GC you have none, without (plain C++) you have (regardless if you use a shared pointer or not)